# Prove that the sum is less than $6/5$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

How to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{15} \frac{1}{n^3}\lt\frac 65$$

I tried to compare this sum to the infinite sum, but *Apery*'s constant is just above $1.2$ so this approach doesn't work.

Then I typed this into wolfy and the sum seems as if it is just under $6/5$.

However, I was wondering if there was a better way of proving this result rather than summing all the terms.

Comment: "just under" is an understatement.  It seems to be $1.199977898\dots$.  What makes you think there's a better method than straight computation?

Comment: @lulu I am not sure if there is a better method, that is why I am asking the community for any suggestions.

Comment: Fair enough.  Alas, I have no ideas.  Striking that it's so close, of course.

Comment: We could improve the question by searching the maximum $N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^3}<\frac65$ is true

Comment: @Joe  I looked at that, the answer is $15$.

Comment: $1/n^3<1/(n^3-n)$ for $n>1$. Resolve this into partial fraction and sum it up.

Comment: @CYKwong that goes way over the bound needed to be established.

Comment: @Displayname yes. Maybe we need a closer estimate, and skip the first few terms when telescoping

Comment: You might see how many terms after $15$ that need to be subtracted from Apery's constant to get that below $1.2$.

Comment: $< {\displaystyle{15^{\left(\,1 - 3\,\right)} \over 1 -  3}} + \zeta\left(\,3\,\right) = \zeta\left(\,3\,\right) - {1 \over 450} \approx 1.1998$

Answer (score 4):

You can estimate the remainder of the series by comparing it to the integral.

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^3}\ge\int_{N}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^3}=\bigg[\frac{-1}{2t^2}\bigg]_{N}^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2N^2}$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{15}\frac 1{n^3}\le\zeta(3)-\frac 1{512}\simeq 1.2001... > \frac 65$

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{14}\frac 1{n^3}\le\zeta(3)-\frac 1{450}\simeq 1.1998... < \frac 65$

Unfortunately the integral comparison cannot tell with certitude if the proper $N$ is $15$, so unless there are other ideas, I think the effective computation is required.

Comment: Actually I think that using the integral comparison to $\int_13^\infty$ then adding in the 2 other terms works in this case. This reduces computation drastically but still requires a good approximation of the Apery constant as well as computation of the sum of two small fractions.

Answer (score 0):

This is just 
a numerical coincidence,
as far as I am concerned.

As others have noted,
according to Wolfy,
the sum to 15 terms is
$$\dfrac{56154295334575853}{46796108014656000}
=1.199977898097614804322644896619336727642969815345853855758...
$$
and the sum to 16 terms is
$$\dfrac{449325761325072949}{374368864117248000}
=1.200222038722614804322644896619336727642969815345853855758...
$$

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably not an answer to the question.*

Consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n^3}=H_p^{(3)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers and use the corresponding asymptotics
$$H_p^{(3)}=\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{2 p^2}+\frac{1}{2 p^3}-\frac{1}{4 p^4}+\frac{1}{12
   p^6}-\frac{1}{12 p^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{10}}\right)$$ where $\zeta (3)\approx 1.20205690316$. Using this value for order $O\left(\frac{1}{p^{k}}\right)$ and computing for $p=15$, we should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & H_{15}^{(3)}\\
0,1 & 1.20205690316 \\
 2 & 1.19983468094 \\
 3 & 1.19998282909 \\
 4,5 & 1.19997789081 \\
 6,7 & 1.19997789813 \\
 8,9 & 1.19997789810 
 \end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

$\sum_{N+1}^{15} (1/x^3) $ < $\int_N^{15} (1/x^3) dx $  Try N=1 ,if it doesn't work,try N=2 etc this comes from the integral test . In fact you should   increase the upper limit of the integral from 15 to  +infinity  to make it easier .I believe N=3 might work

Comment: Sorry N=3 and as explained by others many higher won't do .